# How do I only show the latest transaction instead of previous transactions C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

The goal is to only show the latest updates to each bank account that has been created. I am not sure how to do this and have tried to use the clear method but that is not working. Currently each time I add a checking or savings account when I click the report button it will show the account multiple times if I have made a withdrawal or deposit. My goal is to only show each account that exist and the current balance not show the account multiple times because I have made multiple transactions. As you see from the screenshots below I create a Checking account# 1 with a starting balance of $300. Then I do another transaction adding $1000 to the checking account and creating a savings account with a starting balance of $300. When I click report again it should only show The checking account with a balance of $1300 and a savings account with a balance of $300. Instead it is showing the previous transaction with new transactions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the code that is sending the data to the report form.

```
    private void reportButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Account account in accounts)
        {
            List<Transaction> transactions = 
            account.GetAccountTransaction();

            allTransactions.AddRange(transactions);
        }

        string reportString = accounts.ToString();

        AccountReportForm destinyForm = new AccountReportForm();
        destinyForm.ExternalData = allTransactions;
        destinyForm.Show();
    }
```

Here is the code in the report form that will display the results.

```
    public partial class AccountReportForm : Form
{
    public List<Transaction> ExternalData { get; set; }
    public AccountReportForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AccountReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataLabel2.Text = "";
        foreach (Transaction endMonth in ExternalData)
        {
            dataLabel2.Text += endMonth.Transactions + "\n";

        }
    }
```

If needed this is the method that is being called in the reportbutton method click. This method is in the savings and checking class.

```
            public override List<Transaction> GetAccountTransaction()
        {
            var transactions = new List<Transaction>();
            var endString = new Transaction();

            string reportString = ("Checking account: " + 
         AccountID.ToString() + " has a balance of $" + Balance.ToString());
            endString.Transactions = reportString;
            transactions.Add(endString);

            return transactions;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you in `reportButton4_Click` is using a variable called `allTransactions` which is not defined in that method. Since you're calling `.AddRange()` on that list it will append the transactions from the account to the current list each time the button is clicked. If you never reset the list it will keep growing. Try to reset the list first:

```
private void reportButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    allTransactions = new List<Transaction>();

    foreach (Account account in accounts)
    {
        List<Transaction> transactions = 
        account.GetAccountTransaction();

        allTransactions.AddRange(transactions);
    }

    string reportString = accounts.ToString();

    AccountReportForm destinyForm = new AccountReportForm();
    destinyForm.ExternalData = allTransactions;
    destinyForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: So I added this at the end allTransactions.Clear(); which resolved the issue.